# installing trousers for tpm emulator

Tags: linux, tpm

I have installed tpm emulator successfully. I get this error

```
* Starting Trusted Computing daemon tcsd    /etc/init.d/trousers: 32: [: /dev/tpm: unexpected operator [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript trousers, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing trousers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when executing

```
sudo apt-get install tpm-tools libtspi-dev
```

Comment: Which distribution do you use?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.0.4 i have used this tutorial [http://eip.epitech.eu/2011/boottruster/howto.php?part=1] to install tpm emulator.

Comment: I want to install TrouSers for communicating with tpm emulator

Comment: You did the `modprobe tpmd_dev`, right? I'm not sure whether you crossed a strange init script bug or you don't have a `/dev/tpm*`. Can you therefore please provide the output of `ls -al /dev/tpm*`?

Comment: I'm having this same problem. My output of `ls -al /dev/tpm*` is this: /dev/tpm (the tpm emulator device)

Comment: here it the output of

Comment: here it the output of root@ubuntu:/home/kashif# ls -al /dev/tpm*
    _crw-rw---- 1 root tss  10, 224 Mar  8 02:27 /dev/tpm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       3 Mar  8 02:27 /dev/tpm0 -> tpm_

Answer (score 0):

The answer to that particular error message is a broken line in the given script `/etc/init.d/trousers`.

The offending line 32:

```
31:
32: if [ ! -e /dev/tpm* ]
33: then
```

gets expanded to:

```
if [ ! -e /dev/tpm /dev/tpm0 ]
```

Which provokes an error. Changing that line to something like:

```
31:
32: if [ ! -e /dev/tpm ] && [ ! -e /dev/tpm0 ]
33: then
```

should at least make the script work.